# Baffeling problem with Powershell

Tags: powershell

ps script to execute from powershell! I have changed the the execution previlage to unrestricted. But when I run a simple script I get the following

[image]

Comment: .ps = postscript, not powershell.

Comment: @x0n, that was a cry for help to implement PowerShell in PostScript so that we can script the hell out of our printers :-)

Comment: @Joey:  Install-NewTonerCartridge

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PowerShell's file extension is `.ps1`, not `.ps`. Just rename the script.